# Using a Variable in a Formula in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to use an user defined variable in a VBA formula. But I am not sure how to embed the variable.

My code is :

```
Order_ID = ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Find(what:="OrderID").Column
RecordType = ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Find(what:="RecordType").Column

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC["&Order_ID&"],RC["&RecordType&"])"
```

But thats giving me syntax error. Could anyone help in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just put a space each side of the ampersands. You should also first check your values are found to avoid errors.

Comment: [Type Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters) in Visual Basic are a thing.